# TAG on Current Repo pointed

Tags: git, tags, git-branch

I Have reseted the workspace to a particular tag, what is the command need to know which tag is pointed to any repository? 
The tag which is reseted == command which used to find the reset tag on any repository...

Answer (score 0):

The real intent of your question is a bit difficult to understand by the words used.  If I understand correctly, you can use:

- `git tag` to list all the tags in a repository
- `git tag -l 'v1.0*'` to perform a search with wildcards
- Once you have located the tag you want (or suspect it is the one you need) you can see details with `git show v1.0`

*Obviously, I have chosen some 'generic' tagnames here.  You need to apply what is appropriate for **your** situation.

Comment: The main theme of the question is, You have created a workspace and reset to a particular tag and after 10days u have seen the workspace then u need to know which tag is used for the workpsace.